# A widget to show tasks that are two days closer to due date

Tags: app-widgets, to-do-list

I am using Jorte application which has a home screen widget to show a list of tasks (synced from Google tasks). But it display all tasks, even the ones that has the due date next month.

Are there any home screen widget that displays tasks that have their due dates within two days from today's date. I do not want to see all tasks.

People who have used Symbian before, would be familiar with this feature. In Symbian, this is a default feature in the homescreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pure Calendar Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.koxx.pure_calendar) (not free) has an option for how many days ahead to show calendar/task entries for.  There is an option for 2 days that would suit your needs perfectly.  Note that you will need a supported app to sync the tasks from Google ([GTasks](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.dayup.gtask), [Astrid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.timsu.astrid), etc.)  See the list of supported task apps [here](http://koxx3.wordpress.com/pure-widgets-descriptions/pure-calendar/).